# jquery собые по клику на внутренних ссылках

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть див-обертка
внутри куча li div a. это меню. Классы у ссылок разные. 
есть ли возможность добавить внутренним ссылкам (тем, что внутри дива-обертки) функцию? 
чтобы при клике на любую ссылку внутри дива она срабатывала

вот пример этого меню

```
<div class="extra-pb1"> /* див-оберка */
    <li id="dc_jqaccordion_widget-2" class="widget ">       
            <div class="dcjq-accordion" id="dc_jqaccordion_widget-2-item">
         <ul id="menu-1" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-208" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-productscat current-menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-item-208 dcjq-parent-li"><a href="1" class="dcjq-parent active">1<span class="dcjq-icon"></span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
            <li id="menu-item-211" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-productscat menu-item-has-children menu-item-211 dcjq-parent-li">
<a href="2" class="dcjq-parent">2<span class="dcjq-icon"></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
```

меню неполное, добавил для примера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".extra-pb1 a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```